# Batch insert using spring data

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, commit

I have 60K records to be inserted. I want to commit the records by batch of 100.

Below is my code

```
for(int i = 0 ;i < 60000; i++) {
   entityRepo.save(entity);
   if(i % 100 == 0) {
      entityManager.flush();
      entityManager.clear();
      LOG.info("Committed = " + i);
   } 
}
entityManager.flush();
entityManager.clear();
```

I keep checking the database whenever I receive the log but I don't see the records getting committed.. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

It is not enough to call `flush()` and `clear()`. You need a reference to the `Transaction` and call `.commit()` (from the [reference guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch04.html#d5e976))

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
for ( int i=0; i<100000; i++ ) {
    Customer customer = new Customer(.....);
    session.save(customer);
}
tx.commit();
session.close();
```

Comment: No. Inject a TransactionManager for Spring

Answer (score 1):

I assume two ways to do this, One as define transaction declarative, and call from external method.

Parent:

```
 List<Domain> domainList = new ArrayList<>();
 for(int i = 0 ;i < 60000; i++) {
    domainList.add(domain);
    if(i%100 == 0){
    child.saveAll(domainList);
    domainList.clear();
    }
 }
```

Child:

```
@Transactional
public void saveAll(List<Domain> domainList) {
}
```

This calls the declarative method at regular intervals as defined by the parent.

The other one is to manually begin and end the transaction and close the session.